# What is the third peak in the spectrum of Sodium-22?

Tags: energy, experimental-physics, spectroscopy

I collected this spectrum from a sodium-22 sample in an instructional laboratory. The sample was set in front of a germanium detector which sends a signal into a pulse height analyzer and plots a histogram according to the energies of detected particles. I know that the first peak at 511 keV is due to positronium annihilation and the second peak is due to a ~1.27 MeV gamma decay. But I can't find any information on what the third peak at ~1.78 MeV ought to be. Does anyone know what the source of this feature is? Note that is isn't very large but it is obviously significant and prominent. Thank you!

[image: Sodium-22 Spectrum]

And here's a close-up on that third peak:

[image: Zoom-in on the third peak]

Comment: It seems to be the peak at the summed energy of the two other peaks and is mentioned in [this document relating to the calibration of a detector](http://rhic22.physics.wayne.edu/SaxumSubluceo/LLOPE_naical.pdf).

Comment: Have you tried adding 511 to 1270? Suggest anything? Does it also explain the difference in height?

Comment: I am inferring from your hint that the third peak represents a coincidence event of a 511 keV and 1270 keV photon hitting at the same time. This would explain the small size of the peak, but then why would we not see also some evidence of a peak at 1022 keV? Is it just that there are so many counts there that the coincidence of two 511 keV photons can't be made out against the background?

Comment: The top plot is on a log scale. You might look more closely (on a linear scale!) where you might expect coincidence of two 511keV gammas.

Comment: Identifying the 2x511 coincidence peak is made harder in this data because it lies very near the Compton edge for the 1270 line, though there is a suggestive burp in the data in the right spot that might (examined in linear scale as @Jan suggests) be something.

Comment: Given that momentum is conserved, think about whether it is possible for the detector to absorb both 511 gammas from the same positron annihilation. The directions of the 1270 and 511 gammas are uncorrelated, so from the Na22 source activity and 1270 and 511 peak sizes, try estimating whether the observed 1270+511 peak size matches that expected from simultaneous detections of 1270 and 511 gammas from the same Na22 decays.  From the time coincidence window of the detector, you can also estimate if you are likely to see a peak from coincidentally detecting two 511 gammas from different decays.